# How to validate selected combobox on datagridview?

Tags: c#, validation, checkbox, datagridview, combobox

I am currently making an excel validation program.

I want to validate the selected KPI values under a specific month.
Say, the selected KPI column box is **"SALES VOLUME"** and the checkbox that is checked is **"JANUARY"**, only SALES VOLUME KPI under JANUARY shall be only validated.

Result example should be like this :

A textfile would pop out showing this values on the selected KPI Combo Box and checkbox of the month.

KPI: Sales Volume

Category: Macau & Shipstore

Month: January

Value: 1283091823

Only the KPI **SALES VOLUME** from the month January shall be validated.

For reference, here's an [image of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhIqJ.png).

My codes are as follows:

From ExcelMethods Class:

This method validates each month depending on the checkbox checked.

```
 public void Validate_Month(DataGridView dataGridView, int month, int select)
    {
        int kpi = 2;
        int category = 3;
        decimal num;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\brandon\InvalidColumnsByMonth.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);

        sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (dataGridView.ColumnCount > 3)
        {
            for (int h = select; h <= month; h++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
                    {
                        if (dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == null || dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() == "") 
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine("[KPI]: " + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[kpi].Value.ToString()); 
                            sb.AppendLine("[Category]: " + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[category].Value.ToString());
                            sb.AppendLine("[Month]:" + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name.ToUpper());
                            sb.AppendLine("[VALUE]:  " + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "");
                            sb.AppendLine("");

                            sw.WriteLine("[KPI]: " + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[kpi].Value.ToString());
                            sw.WriteLine("[Category]: " + dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[category].Value.ToString());
                            sw.WriteLine("[Month]:" + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name.ToUpper());
                            sw.WriteLine("[VALUE]: {" + dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString() + "}");
                            sw.WriteLine("");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sb.Length != 0 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
                Process.Start(@"C:\brandon\InvalidColumnsByMonth.txt");

            }

            else
            {
                int h = select;

                MessageBox.Show("No errors in month of " + dataGridView.Columns[h].Name + ".");
            }

            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

        }
    }
```

From my Form 1 Class

This is for reference ExcelMethods method, Validate_Month

```
 public void Validate(CheckBox cb, DataGridView dataGridView1, String month, int i)
    {
        if (cb.Checked == true && dataGridView1.Columns.Contains(month) )
        {
            ExcelMethods.Validate_Month(dataGridView1, 4 + i, 4 + i);
        }
    }
```

and lastly, from Form 1 Class is the btnValidateAll_MouseClick method

```
 private void btnValidate_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Validate(checkBox1, dataGridView1, "January", 0);
        Validate(checkBox2, dataGridView1, "February", 1);
        Validate(checkBox3, dataGridView1, "March", 2);
        Validate(checkBox4, dataGridView1, "April", 3);
        Validate(checkBox5, dataGridView1, "May", 4);
        Validate(checkBox6, dataGridView1, "June", 5);
        Validate(checkBox7, dataGridView1, "July", 6);
        Validate(checkBox8, dataGridView1, "August", 7);
        Validate(checkBox9, dataGridView1, "September", 8);
        Validate(checkBox10, dataGridView1, "October", 9);
        Validate(checkBox11, dataGridView1, "November", 10);
        Validate(checkBox12, dataGridView1, "December", 11);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the validating method to do grid validation.  Make sure the grid has the event attached.

e has the column and row index property.  You can set the e.Cancel to true to assign it to not validated.

```
private void dataGridView_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{

    // Gets Your Row & Column, 4 is Jan in this case
    if ( e.ColumnIndex == 4 && e.RowIndex >= 0 )
    {

        // Do Your Validation
        // If False. Set 
        // e.Cancel = true;


    }
}
```

Or based on your definition of validate:

Change your method definition:

```
public void Validate_Month(DataGridView dataGridView, int month, int select, string kpi)
```

Change your validation:

```
if ((dataGridView[2, i].Value.ToString() == kpi || kpi == "" || kpi == null) &&  !Decimal.TryParse(dataGridView[h, i].Value.ToString(), out num))
```

This way it'll only match on the matching kpi.  I've set that up so it'll also match all rows if kpi is passed in as blank or null.

Comment: I might have used the word, "Validate" incorrectly.

By validate means to check for errors not the "method".

Lastly, I would like to clarify only the KPI COLUMNS under JANUARY should be validated. Say, KPI Column Selected is "SALES VOLUME", it would only check only that. I have already made the code, I just want to filter it out.

Comment: added more notes

Comment: It seems like I'm receiving an error when I change sheet.

Comment: Anyway, I resolved it. Thanks!

I'll vote you for best answer.